# css mouseover - Works in FF but not in IE

Tags: css

I have the following css which works when I mouse over it in Firefox but not IE(6).

```
.PageMenu{
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    list-style-position:outside;
}

.PageMenu li{

    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;

}

ul#PageMenu li:hover {
   color: #000;
   background-color: #ddd; 
}
```

The HTML is:

```
<ul class="PageMenu" id="PageMenu">
    <li>       
        <a title="test" class="getPage">Click this link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a title="test" href="#" class="getPage">Link text</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm looking for a css solution which will work in both IE(specifically 6) and Firefox.

Comment: IE6!!!!!!!!!! It's a deprecated browser test your app in IE8.

Comment: This runs on an intranet, IE6 is the only browser the users have. This isn't going to change any time soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign a `:hover` rule to anything but `<a>` elements in IE6. Try

```
ul#PageMenu a:hover {
   color: #000;
   background-color: #ddd;
}


ul#PageMenu a {
   display: block;
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I think he wants the `li` to have a hover style? The `a:hover` will not really look the same. Good info however.

Comment: edited css for the anchor to overlay li, so the effect is the same.

Comment: This will make the entire `li` clickable, I don't think the OP would want that, from what he is describing I imagine it is just to make browsing the lines easier by highlighting the hovered over line?

Comment: Looking at the sample HTML there is nothing else in the li other than a link, so I see no reason why blocking the link and styling it instead of the li would be a problem.

Comment: Thank you Raveren. I removed width:100 and this works perfectly

Comment: I think submitting this as an answer might be better :)

Answer (score 0):

Running this HTC file seems to be the cleanest method:

Download this file:
http://www.kavoir.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/csshover3.htc

Then add this to your CSS:

```
body {
    behavior:url("/styles/csshover3.htc");
}
```

Otherwise you will need to go with JS, which is rather fugly:

```
if (!window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
        $$('ul#PageMenu li').each( function(e) {
            Event.observe(e, 'mouseover', function() {
                Element.addClassName(e, 'hover');
            });
            Event.observe(e, 'mouseout', function() {
                Element.removeClassName(e, 'hover');
            });
        )};
    )};
}
```

Personally I don't see why you are still trying to support IE6, or even IE7, is there a particular reason?

Comment: Myles, this is for an intranet. The company has ~7000 computers all run IE6 because of multi million euro software which needs this setup. They can't install any other software.

Comment: Understood man, Well try out the above, If you don't want that then try the JS solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make the `<a>` element clickable by using jQuery. It goes along the line of:

```
$('#PageMenu li').click(function(e) {
    window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Perhaps you might want to give the `<li>` element a CSS style for cursor, such as `cursor: pointer`